# A problem concerning an integrated function such that for every $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$ , $ f(x)=0$

Tags: calculus, integration

$f(x)$ is  integrated in every closed interval that contained in $R$ and 
$f(x) = \int_0^x {f(t)dt} $ $\;\;$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$

proove that for every $x\in \mathbb{R}$ ; $f(x)=0$
.

I tried to show this by definition.with no success.
Will be glad to hear ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that any solution to your equation is differentiable, since
$$\frac{f(t)-f(s)}{t-s} =\frac{1}{t-s}\int_s^t f(y)dy$$ and
$$ \frac{1}{t-s}\int_s^t f(y)dy \rightarrow f(s) \,\, (\text{when } t\rightarrow s)$$
(Depending on the regularity assumptions on $f$ this is more or less easy to see).

In particular any solution will satisfy the differential equation $f^\prime =f$ 
Now assume $f$ solves the equation and consider $g(t):= f(t)e^{-t}$. Then
$$g^\prime(t) = f^\prime(t)e^{-t} - f(t) e^{-t}= 0$$
in other words, $g$ is constant, $g(t)=c$ which implies (!) that necessarily
$$f(t)= ce^t$$
which in turn implies $f(t) = 0$ if $f(y_0)= 0$ for some $y_0$. Since $f(0) = 0$ (obviously) $f(x) = 0$ for every $x$.

Answer (score 1):

First you see that

$$f(0)=\int_0^0f(t)dt=0 \tag{1}$$

Then you can use

$$f(x)=\int_0^x f'(t)dt+c_1=\int_0^xf(t) \tag2$$

Using (1) $c_1=0$ you end up with the differential equation

$$f(x)=f'(x) \tag3$$
Which has the solution $f(x)=c_2\cdot e^x $. Also using (1) you see that $c_2$ must also be zero.
Then you get $$\forall x R\,:\;f(x)=0$$

Comment: This is fine, with the exception that you need to show (or have to know) that $c e^x$ is the only (unique) solution to that differential equation. (The qeuestion was why $0$ is the _only_ solution. This follows only if $ce^x$ is the unique solution to $f^\prime = f$)

Comment: Also, you would need to justify what $f^\prime$ exists, i.e. [why is $f$ differentiable in the first place.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Generalizations) $f$ is not assumed to be continuous to begin with...

Comment: @ClementC. There already has been a comment to that end (by now deleted). It is quite obvious that $f$ is differentiable if is satisfies the equation. Admittedly this should be commented on.

Comment: @Thomas It is quite obvious, but still requires saying (I cannot see deleted comments -- and would assume most people can't...). If $f$ was assumed continuous, I'd deem it less important, but here presumably we can only assume $f$ locally integrable to begin with.

Comment: @ClementC. As I said, it should be commented on.

Comment: @ClementC. why is $f$ continuous ?
I understood I need to show why $f$ is differentiable ?
how can I how this ?

Comment: The answer depends a lot on the problem itself. Is there any assumption on $f$ you may have forgotten to write? What theory of integration are you using? From the link given above, without any other assumption it looks to me (I may be wrong) one can only say that $f$ is differentiable almost everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f$ is given integrable on [0,x], by second fundamental theorem of calculus  $f(t)=g(t)=\int_0^t f$ is a  continuous function of $t$ on [0,x] . Again using the same theorem, $g=f$ is differentiable on [0,x], where $f'=g'=f$. Rest follows as in other comments.

Comment: why $f$ is continuous ? and why $f$ is differentiable ?

Comment: Because $f$ is integrable so $f$ is bounded, say |f|<M. Then for any $\epsilon >0$, $|f(t)-f(s)|=|\int_t^s f| \leq \int_t^s |f|\leq M |t-s|<\delta=\epsilon$. So continuity follows